# Copy data from Azure Storage to Filesystem using Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks

I have a csv file that contains the source and target folder mappings.

The file resides on Azure Storage and looks like the below.

```
source, target
Container1, \\Filesystem-root\Folder1
Container2, \\Filesystem-root\Folder2
Container3, \\Filesystem-root\Folder3
```

I want to read this csv file into the ADF (which i have done using Databricks notebook and sending the above as a list of lists as shown below).

```
   "runOutput": [
        [
            "CONTAINER1",
            "\\\\Filesystem-root\FOLDER1"
        ],
        [
            "CONTAINER2",
            "\\\\Filesystem-root\FOLDER2"
        ],
        [
            "CONTAINER3",
            "\\\\Filesystem-root\FOLDER3"
        ],
```

The problem is that I dont understand how can i split these lists into individual items and copy the data from source to target (from Containers to Folders on Filesystem).

So the copy activity has "CONTAINER[n]" as Source and Folder[n] as target.

Also python adds extra "\" to the folder path, which i couldn't figure out how to fix in the code, so may need to split the path in ADF and reconstruct to remvoe the extra "\"

Each container goes to a separate folder on the filesystem.

Any Help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Since you have array of array with each element folding the source and destination path (at indices 0 and 1 respectively), you can use for each loop to iterate through this array and use them in the source and destination paths of your copy data activity.
- The following is a demonstration of the same. I have taken the following as my sample array (as a parameter).

```
[["s1","d1"],["s2","d2"],["s3","d3"]]
```

[image]

- Now iterate through this array in a for each loop as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Inside for each I have 2 set variable activities, source path and destination path with values as `@items()[0] and @items()[1]` respectively.
- The output of source path (for last iteration) would be as shown in the below image:

[image]

- The destination path (for last iteration) would be as shown in the below image:

[image]

- The following is the pipeline JSON for above demonstrated pipeline.

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.paths",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "source path",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "src",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@item()[0]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "destination path",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "source path",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "dest",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@item()[1]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "paths": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    [
                        "s1",
                        "d1"
                    ],
                    [
                        "s2",
                        "d2"
                    ],
                    [
                        "s3",
                        "d3"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "dest": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "src": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The additional `\` are just escape characters. So there is no need to worry about them as long as the path is valid.